# Javascript detect when inner html has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried attaching the even onchange and change(with jquery) to an element that updates every couple seconds. Neither of these events are raised when the inner html is changed.
How can I detect with with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Do you control the updates? If so, just trigger a custom event whenever you update, and define a handler for it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for the [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) event? See the [DOM event reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference).

Answer (score 0):

is it updating by ajax? can't you just store the value before the call is made and compare it with what is returned?